# Do married cancer patients have lower death rates than single cancer patients?

Tags: cancer, marriage

This article posted on a Russian news portal claims that American scientists have found a beneficial effect of marriage at treating cancer:

> Как сообщает Lifenews со ссылкой на The Washington Post, учёные Скарлет Лин Гомес из Института по профилактике рака и Мария Элена Мартинез из Калифорнийского университета Сан-Диего наблюдали за пациентами, диагноз которым был поставлен с 2000 года по 2009 год.
>
> Они обнаружили, что люди, не состоящие в браке, умирали от рака чаще, чем семейные. При этом самая высокая вероятность излечения — у мужчин, состоящих в браке.
>
> Согласно результатам исследования, у мужчин, не состоявших в браке, смертность была на 27% выше, чем у женатых. В то же самое время смертность одиноких женщин была на 19% выше, чем у замужних.

Translation:

> Scarlett Lin Gomez and Maria Elena Martinez, scientists from the Institute for Cancer Prevention and the University of California San Diego have watched patients diagnosed with cancer since 2000 to 2009.
>
> They found that single people died from cancer more often than those married. And that patients with highest probability of recovery were married men.
>
> According to the study, the mortality rate of unmarried men was 27% higher than that of married men. At the same time, the death rate of single women was 19% higher than that of married.

[Source](http://lifenews.ru/news/196287)

Comment: A small nitpick: the world isn't divided in "married" and "single" patients.

Comment: @Sklivvz My dictionary gives "unmarried" as a synonym for "single", so it seems reasonable to me in the context of a medical study.

Comment: I would be surprised if there wasn't--having a caretaker in the house when undergoing major medical treatment is a good thing!

Comment: Does a couple that's been together for fifty years unmarried come under the heading of two single people?

Comment: @PointlessSpike, I hope not...

Comment: Regardless of whether or not those are the only two groups, those groups are valid to compare to one another just as you can compare white incarceration to black incarceration despite there being more races in the world.  Small and pointless nitpick.

Comment: Yes, but it changes the result a lot. If they claim the marriage is the result, they're missing out on the obvious: it's having a person who loves you and takes care of you; regardless of whether you signed any documents or had any ceremonies.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Russian text talks about married and unmarried, not single. Single in modern US English means someone who is not in a relationship which is different than unmarried.

Comment: My nitpick is: Causality may be reversed. If you die of cancer at age 21, you probably never got a chance to be married. If you were seriously ill, you may have had fewer opportunities to meet/retain a partner.